# C# webBrowser1 does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, web

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate("www.google.com");
        }
    }
}
```

After inserting above code I get this message: The name webBrowser1 does not exist in the current conext. 
How to get webBrowser1 work?

Comment: Have you added the webBrowser1 control on your form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access a windows form control without actually adding it to your application.

Go to the designer view of the form and make sure that there is a Web Browser control in the form named webBrowser1.

Comment: Can you explain that more precisely. I don't get it.

Comment: did you add a webBrowser control in the form? If you didn't. drag a webborwser control from the toolbox and drop it in the form. and make sure it has the name webBrowser1. you can check the name by selecting the webbrowser control and looking for Name property in the properties panel

Comment: It works smoothly. Great work. Thank you for your help.